# How do I change IKImageBrowserView's selection highlight color

Tags: xcode, cocoa, ikimagebrowserview

When you select an item in IKImageBrowserView it is highlighted grey around the edges. How do I change the color of this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was able to achive what I was looking for by going the complex route that combinatorial suggested (Thanks!). I implemented the custom IKImageBrowserView and IKImageBrowserCell classes from the sample project here: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#/legacy/mac/library/samplecode/ImageKitDemo/Introduction/Intro.html

Too bad there isn't an easier way to do this but this will do the trick for now.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the "View Options Keys" in the [IKImageBrowserView documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/Reference/IKImageBrowserView/IKImageBrowserView_Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/IKImageBrowserSelectionColorKey). I think that IKImageBrowserSelectionColorKey should do the trick.

So you code will be something like this in awakeFromNib of your view controller:

```
[imageBrowserView setValue:[NSColor blueColor] forKey:IKImageBrowserSelectionColorKey];
```

Comment: This changes the color of the title highlight. What I'm looking for is the highlight of the image view. I have updated my question with a picture of what I'm talking about.

Comment: To get that effect then I think you have to go the complex route. You need to implement a custom IKImageBrowserView class that implements  -(IKImageBrowserCell *)newCellForRepresentedItem:(id)anItem and that method need to return a custom cell object that implements -(CALayer *)layerForType:(NSString *) type. see http://developer.apple.com/legacy/mac/library/#samplecode/ImageKitDemo/Listings/Step7_ImageBrowserCell_m.html

Answer (score 0):

```
[imageBrowserView setValue:[NSColor blueColor] forKey:IKImageBrowserCellsOutlineColorKey];
```